# Unset Nested Array by Comparison

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, multidimensional-array, foreach

Thank you for taking your time to look at this question.

I have a database entry that contains a serialized array (of multiple arrays).  It might look like this:

### Array 1

```
a:2:{
  i:0;a:3:{s:11:"search_type";s:6:"owners";s:11:"search_text";s:4:"test";s:11:"search_name";s:4:"test";}
  i:1;a:5:{s:8:"t_rating";s:3:"Yes";s:9:"t_ranking";s:3:"Yes";s:11:"search_type";s:8:"products";s:11:"search_text";s:5:"test2";s:11:"search_name";s:5:"test2";}
}
```

Then, I have another serialized array being passed that might look like this:

### Array 2

```
a:2:{s:11:"search_type";s:6:"owners";s:11:"search_text";s:4:"test";}
```

### Conditions

- Array 1 can have any number of nested arrays (my example shows 2).
- Array 2 is passed from a selector; which should loop Array 1 and remove it's associated nested array.
- These arrays are being compared using PHP.

### The Problem

The issue is that each array in Array 1 needs to first remove the "search_name" array key before making the comparison.

The "search_name" key from Array 1 should never be used for comparison.  When the "search_name" key is removed; a valid comparison of the serialized arrays can then be made.

But, when this gets updated to the db; the non-removed arrays should still contain the "search_name" key.  It only needs to be removed for comparison; then it's full array should be removed from Array 1.

### My (Broken) Code

Here is what I currently have:

```
$search_array = unserialize($_POST['search_array']);  // Serialized Array 2
$bm_adv_search = $query_adv_search[0]->bm_adv_search;  // Serialized Array 1

$unser_array = unserialize($bm_adv_search);  // Unserialize Array 1

// Unset search_name from each array in Array 1
foreach($unser_array as $key => $value) {

    unset($unser_array[$key]['search_name']);  // THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA
}

// Unset Array 2 from Array 1
if(in_array($search_array, $unser_array)) {
    if(($key = array_search($search_array, $unser_array)) !== false) {
        unset($unser_array[$key]);
    }
}

// Re-Serialize Array 1
$reser_array = serialize($unser_array);

// Update db with Array 1
.....
```

So when I update Array 1 to the db; the name field has been removed from all nested arrays, which when updated, excludes the "search_name".

I need the "search_name" to stay in each array from Array 1 when updated.  I just need to remove it for comparison purposes... and then remove the nested array from Array 1.

### The Idea

Basically, I am storing user saved bookmarks.  When a user bookmarks an item; a serialized array gets added to Array 1.  A user is prompted to enter a "Name" for the search bookmark; hence the "search_name" field.

When a user clicks to remove a bookmark; the "search_name" key is not available in the comparison array (Array 2).  Array 1 should be looped for Array 2's existence (minus the "search_name" key)... and the entire matched array (including "search_name") should be unset.

Again, thank you for any time on this question.  I really appreciate any assistance.

### UPDATE

Got it working.  Thanks Mikel!!

Here is the updated code:

```
$search_array = unserialize($_POST['search_array']);  // Serialized Array 2
$bm_adv_search = $query_adv_search[0]->bm_adv_search;  // Serialized Array 1

$unser_array = unserialize($bm_adv_search);  // Unserialize Array 1

// Clone Array 1
$compare_array = $unser_array; 

// Unset search_name from each array in cloned Array 1
foreach($compare_array as $key => $value) {

    unset($compare_array[$key]['search_name']); 
}

// Unset Array 2 from Array 1
if(in_array($search_array, $compare_array)) {
    if(($key = array_search($search_array, $compare_array)) !== false) {
        unset($unser_array[$key]);
    }
}

// Re-Serialize Array 1
$reser_array = serialize($unser_array);

// Update db with Array 1
.....
```

Comment: Your comment says "Unset Array 1 from Array 2", but you're unset is operating on the $unser_array, which is actually Array 1. So, you're checking array 2 vs array 1 but you're removing from array 1 when you state you want to remove from array 2? - I just realized that this comment could mean either way, heh.

EDIT: Why not just copy array1 to a temporary array for comparison, but do any true modifications to the main $unser_array. Could be as simple as $compar_array = $unser_array and then modifying a few of the vars throughout the code.

Comment: You're right, Mikel.  Thank you very much.  Edited above.  EDIT:  Thanks Mikel, I'm not sure how to compare the modified to the original (perhaps by array keys?)... but I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your "Array 1" to a temporary array for comparison, but do any true modifications to the main $unser_array.

Could be as simple as $compar_array = $unser_array and then modifying a few of the vars throughout the code.

You can then compare the two by array key, as they keys will be identical in the arrays. (you just created this copy)

Lemme know if you need any help!

Comment: Working on a fiddle now.. thank you very much!  Brb.

Comment: Got it, mate.  Updated my question.  I'm still not exactly sure "why" it works... but it works great.  Thank you for your time.  As soon as I have enough rep; I'll come back to upvote (won't let me yet).  Thank you!!

Comment: @josh401 No problem! You rocked this question, honestly. It's a fairly basic question but your effort and willingness to attempt to write the code from the concept is impressive- unfortunately that drive is lost on many members of SO. Great work! I've upvoted all of your posts here, hopefully you can vote soon :)

Comment: Thanks Mikel.  You rock also!  It was a long day, and it was the last item to accomplish.  I think I was just tired.. lol.  But you nailed it perfectly; thank you.  I am a WordPress moderator and write lots of custom code for other projects.  I had an SO account.. and lost the login info... so had to begin anew.  Hope to see you around in the future!